# Will a CC1120 IC be burnt during transmission if antenna is removed

Tags: rf, antenna

I am using a TI CC1120 evaluation kit which is working in the 800MHz band amplified by a C1190 to a 27dBm output power.

I would like to know if it would damage the board to be used with no antenna connected to the SMA adapter.

I am curious about the reflected power. Would it be reflected back to the chip and damage the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CC1190 can withstand an input level of 10dBm, and have an SWR of about 10 without antenna. Since power levels are relatively low (27dBm max) you will not damage the amplifier. I use a similar design to the evaluation board and without any antenna connected, no damage happened, however, I did experience an increased current consumption of ~350mA without an antenna, compared to normal TX current of ~250mA.